# %*s Format specifier C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

`printf("%d",printf("%*s%*s",6,"",6))`

Results in the addition of the 2 numbers (6+6), does anyone have on such type of format specifiers

Comment: The term you are looking for is "nested". If you google "nested printf" you will find alot of information.. Since you don't state a clear question it's hard to anwer..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is malformed, there's a missing argument to the "nested" `printf`.

If you write it like this:

```
printf("%d",printf("%*s%*s",6,"",6, ""));
```

if becomes kind of ok. The `*` means that the precision field must be read from the next argument to `printf`. So in this case, the "nested" `printf` prints two strings of length at most 6.

Since `printf` returns the number of characters written, the inner `printf` returns 12, which the outer `printf` prints.

Quote from the relevant part of the man page:

> The precision
>
> An optional precision, in the form of a period ('.')  followed by an optional decimal digit  string.
>          Instead of a decimal digit string one may write **"*"** or "*m$" (for some decimal integer m) to specify
>          that the precision is given in the next argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which  must
>          be  of type int.  If the precision is given as just '.', or the precision is negative, the precision
>          is taken to be zero.  This gives the minimum number of digits to appear for d, i, o,  u,  x,  and  X
>          conversions,  the number of digits to appear after the radix character for a, A, e, E, f, and F con‐
>          versions, the maximum number of significant digits for g and G conversions, or **the maximum number of
>          characters to be printed from a string for s and S conversions.**

I'm not sure how portable this is, but what I'm sure of is that there are **much better ways to add two numbers**.

Answer (score 1):

A * as the width specifier indicates that the width is passed in as a parameter.

```
printf("%*s%*s", 6, "", 6, "");
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf("%6s%6s", "", "");
```

This would print out 12 spaces.

Since `printf` returns the number of characters printed, it will return 12.

The original code is missing the final "" parameter. If it works, it is purely by accident.

Answer (score -1):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: -1, we _all_ know you're the definitive genius but you should realize not everyone is as intelligent as you.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry. I hoped that this would be all that the author needed to understand where the "12" comes from. I won't bother improving my answer now though, since someone else has already done a great job.